# Convert Redis hash to JSON - PHP

Tags: php, redis

Can anyone please advise how I can convert a `redis` hash to `JSON` in php?

For example I set a `hash` like this;

```
HSET users:goku race sayan
HSET users:goku power 9001
```

And I want get it to this form;

```
$user_from_redis = {race: 'sayan', power: 9001}
```

Any advice appreciated!

Comment: Explode for space, form it to an array and do an json_encode on it? Probably not the nicest solution.